Accessing statefull widget method in button widget file in flutter
I have this class name calculatorscreen inside that class I have function onBtnTap
import 'buttonWidget.dart';
import 'button_values.dart';
class CalculatorScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const CalculatorScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<CalculatorScreen> createState() => _CalculatorScreenState();
}

class _CalculatorScreenState extends State<CalculatorScreen> {
  String firstNumber = ""; //. 0-9
  String operand = ""; //+-*/
  String secondNumber = "";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  }
  void onBtnTap(String value){
    if(value == Btn.calculate){
      calculate();
      return;
    }
    setState((){
      firstNumber+=value;
    });
  }
  void calculate(){
     
  }

}


and trying to access onBtnTap inside my widget file buildButton and onBtnTap is accessing calculatorscreen functions that is calculate
import 'calculator_screen.dart';
import 'button_values.dart';

Widget buildButton(value){

  return Padding(
  );

  
}

i tried global key but it didn't work also
final CalculatorScreen calScreen = new CalculatorScreen(); this method didn't work
Notei removed most of the code that was unnecessary for my question.

You could put your buildButton function inside the _CalculatorScreenState, then use setState directly in buildButton.
Otherwise, pass onBtnTap as a parameter to the child widget, or the build function.
    return buildButton(10,onBtnTap);

Widget buildButton(int value, VoidCallback onTap) {
  return TextButton(
    onPressed: onTap,
    child: Text("$value"),
  );
}


But I want to have BuildButton as a widget in different file and I want to call 'setState' from calculatorscreen, I don't know if it's possible or not, but this is what I am trying to achieve

As shown in the code provided. You can pass the function onBtnTap or even setState as a parameter to the buildButton in the other file.

well, I could not figure out how this callback works; can you provide me some reference so I can understand this concept

You need to provide more context on where buildButton is used in your code

here  you can find that file on git hub. I moved my buildButton in same class as _calculatorScreenState because I could not figure out how to do it. what I want is, to move buildButton and colorlist in another file but rest of the functionality in same file.

I also edited my question kindly review it.

More detailed answer on how to create reusable component with callback.
First create Button component
// button_component.dart

import "package:flutter/material.dart";

Widget buildButton(VoidCallback onPressed, Widget child) {
  return TextButton(
    onPressed: onPressed,
    child: child,
  );
}

Then you can use above component in your stateful widget as shown below
// calculator_component.dart
import "package:flutter/material.dart";
import "package:test_project/components/button_component.dart";

class CalculatorScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const CalculatorScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<CalculatorScreen> createState() => _CalculatorScreenState();
}

class _CalculatorScreenState extends State<CalculatorScreen> {
  String _output = "0";

  /* Btn Pressed Handler */
  void _onButtonPressed(String value) {
    setState(() {
      _output = value;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Text(_output),
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Row(
                children: [
                  buildButton(() => _onButtonPressed("1"), const Text("1")),
                  buildButton(() => _onButtonPressed("2"), const Text("2")),
                  buildButton(() => _onButtonPressed("3"), const Text("3")),
                ],
              );
            }),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

